# CompletableFuture thenCompose after exceptionally

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-webflux, project-reactor, completable-future

I'm stuck with CompletableFuture exception handling

My logic is to send email and save status of this action. If send email throws exception I need to save the status with the exception message.

```
public interface MyService {
CompletableFuture<Boolean> sendEmail(String content, String address);
CompletableFuture<StatusResult> saveStatus(String content, String address);}
```

Processor class currently has this code. It works properly, but is not graceful as for me. How can we get rid of error  local field that we use to share state between stages?

```
@Component
public class Processor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Processor.class);
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public CompletableFuture<StatusResult> sendEmail(String content, String address) {
        AtomicReference<String> error = new AtomicReference<>();// just to forward error message from exception block to thenCompose
        return myService.sendEmail(content, address).exceptionally(e -> {
            LOGGER.error("Exception during send email ", e);
            error.set(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }).thenCompose(x -> {
            if (x == null) {
                return myService.saveStatus(error.get(), address);
            } else {
                return myService.saveStatus("good", address);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Looks like **handle** method should help, but it returns CompletableFuture of CompletableFuture

```
 public CompletableFuture<StatusResult> sendEmail(String content, String address) {
    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<StatusResult>> result = myService.sendEmail(content, address).handle((x, e) -> {
        if (e != null) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception during send email ", e);
            return myService.saveStatus("error", address);
        } else {
            return myService.saveStatus("good", address);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need two CompletableFutures. sendEmail is already running in a separate thread, just have it wait on saveStatus and return the result.

Comment: I cannot block at all, because it works with Spring WebFlux.Blocking will affect all requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to your save status upfront.

```
public CompletableFuture<String> sendEmail(String content, String address) {

    return myService.sendEmail(content, address)
            .thenApply(b -> "good")
            .exceptionally(Throwable::getMessage)
            .thenCompose(status -> myService.saveStatus(status, address));
}
```

Comment: Very elegant. Kudos.

Answer (score -1):

Another working solution :

```
public CompletableFuture<StatusResult> sendEmailAndSaveStatus(String content, String address) {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> sendEmail = myService.sendEmail(content, address);
    CompletableFuture<StatusResult> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    sendEmail.exceptionally(e -> {
        LOGGER.info("Exception during send email ");
        myService.saveStatus(e.getMessage(), address).thenApply(x -> result.complete(x));
        return false;
    });
    sendEmail.thenCompose(x -> myService.saveStatus("good", address)).thenApply(x -> result.complete(x));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because you are chaining two handlers (completion stages) to the same `CompletableFuture<> sendEmail` - one of them will happen and the other will not. Also, instead of creating a second completable future, you can just use `thenApply` to convert one to the other type.